# Get the current active tab from background.js after pages are already loaded

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a Firefox WebExtension. I need to get the current active tab, however, with some additional points. I've successfully managed to get the current active tab from both content script and backgrounde script, however, the events are rised when the page is loaded. The point of my question is that I need to get the active tab even after the pages are loaded. For example, I have 2 tabs in the browser, I managed to get their URL when they are loaded, but when I navigate between them later(when they are already loaded and opened) - I don't get any information. I've managed to solve this question using Alarm(in background script) which will query the current active tab and give me the needed result.

But is it there any better approach to this question? How can I do that without alarms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the active tab at any time from the background script with [tabs.query()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query)

```
const querying = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
querying.then(logTabs, onError);
```

**Update on comment**

That is how you get the active tab from background. 
The timing is up to you. There are [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs#Events) that you can listen to in order to know when to run the code such as:

- tabs.onActivated
- tabs.onAttached
- tabs.onCreated
- tabs.onDetached
- tabs.onHighlighted
- tabs.onMoved
- tabs.onRemoved
- tabs.onReplaced
- tabs.onUpdated
- tabs.onZoomChange

There are also events that can be triggered from the content script and sent to background script with [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage).

It all depends on the situation and when you want to trigger the code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @erosman. I've used that code, but it is executed only once when the page is loaded for the first time. But when it is already opened and when I navigate between the tabs the query is silent. I use firefox developer edition, maybe it is useful to write.